# Intuition behind using random variables in Monte Carlo methods / localization

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, intuition, sampling, monte-carlo

I am trying to get a better intuitive understanding of why [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) works so well in approximating a solution to complex problems, such as calculating irrational numbers or the Particle Filter / Monte Carlo Localization to interpret noisy data from a sensor for instance. I have restated my question in two parts.

**Part 1:** One of [the key's to random sampling](https://youtu.be/OgO1gpXSUzU?t=215) is that the random sample will reflect the characteristics of the population from which it is drawn. So when we approximate Pi [by defining an area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method#Overview) with a circle-quadrant within a square box and let random samples inside vs. outside the quadrant approach the ratio of Pi, are we in essence re-sampling our "deterministicly" defined circle-quadrant and box, using random variables as a mechanism for re-sampling the pre-defined area over and over again?

**Part 2:** My question stated differently with Monte Carlo Localization (MCL); if I understand correctly, we first [scatter random particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_localization#Example_for_1D_robot) (our random sampling/"hypotheses") across our map and then attach larger weight to the particles that overlap/match with our noisy sensor readings as more important. We then repeat to do a new re-sampling. Are the random variables here used as a "fair" measurement mechanism to allow the obscured truth hidden in our noisy sensor reading to be re-sampled so that we approach a cleaner approximate sensor-reading/localization?

***So in summary**, are the random variables here acting as a tool/mechanism for us to be able to create multiple observations of an otherwise deterministic experiment? And if so, at each iteration which we are observing and measuring, how does this avoid simply adding random noise to the data?*

**Or is there a better way to view the work the random variables do here?**

Also, if appropriate, any recommended further reading (including books/papers) that you think can help with the intuition in this mechanism is much appreciated!

[Edit] See answered question at [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412594/intuition-of-the-work-done-by-random-variables-in-monte-carlo-methods-incl-m)

Comment: I don't think the computation of $\pi$ is a good example. Grid sampling would work as well and is feasible in this case. But imagine instead you wanted to compute the volume of the $d$-dimensional unit ball: grid sampling with a mesh of $1/N$ would require $N^d$ samples – not very feasible for $d \gg 1$. What Monte Carlo sampling offers over grid sampling in this scenario is a way to directly control the number of samples to evaluate.

Comment: Montecarlo method is just one of the applications of the law of large numbers. Some of the more un-intuitive applications rely on ergodic theorems

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks for your input. Hmm, why do you think that Pi is a bad example? Isn't there also an analytical way to compute the volume of a d-dimensional ball by its relation to the surface area/mesh?

Comment: @Masacroso ok, I can see that LLN is at work as we repeat the method. But what is at work with the random variables *at each* iteration (of the method)? I.e. am I correct in stating that we are using random variables as a mechanism for re-sampling the pre-defined area over and over again?

Comment: also asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/412594/11260

Comment: @litmus Yes, but I am not talking about analytical methods.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, that I understood. But it surprised me that you thought it a better example to use MC to solve a volume problem (which has an analytical solution), rather than approximating Pi  (which has no analytical solution), since the question was not about computational feasibility but the effect of the random variables.

Comment: There are [analytical formulae for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Formulae_yielding_%CF%80) too. Some of these are far more efficient than any method based on numerical integration.